# postgresql How to share cte among different tables in plain sql?

Tags: postgresql

Say `select id from some_expensive_query` is the cte I want to share. Currently I write two sql in a transaction:

```
with t as (select id from some_expensive_query) select * from  t1 join t on t.id =t1.id;
with t as (select id from some_expensive_query) select * from  t2 join t on t.id =t2.id;
```

As you can see, the cte is executed twice but I want something like:

```
t = select id from some_expensive_query;
select * from  t1 join t on t.id =t1.id;
select * from  t2 join t on t.id =t2.id;
```

for portability, I don't want to use pgsql or functions, anyway to solve this?

Comment: `create temp table t as select from expensive_query`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `union all` ?

```
with t as (select id from some_expensive_query) 
select * from  t1 join t on t.id =t1.id
union all
select * from  t2 join t on t.id =t2.id;
```

Comment: ERROR: each UNION query must have the same number of columns (48)

Comment: It's up to you to retieve the same number of column in each select